# Problems extracting data from pandas data frame as a result of Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, grouping

In order to plot the frequency of tornados every 10 days I have grouped the data in groups of 10 days using

```py
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame()
df_grouped['COUNT'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='10D'))['DATE'].count().to_frame()
```

however the column `DATE` does not exist in the code as shown when I run:

```py
>>> df_grouped.shape
(1041,1)
```

despite the fact that I am able to view and plot the dates in the Jupiter notebook GUI [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnCiv.png).

This is an issue as I wish to access this data later for other purposes and I am unable to using:

```py
year = pd.to_datetime(df_grouped['DATE'], dayfirst = True, errors='coerce').dt.year.values
df_grouped['year'] = year
```

It states that there is an invalid indexing error since the column no longe exists. Does anyone know what I can do to access the data?

---

**MINIMUM REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1994-01-01', end='1994-01-21'), columns=['DATE'])
```

```py
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame()
df_grouped['COUNT'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='10D'))['DATE'].count().to_frame()
```

expected output

```
|DATE      |COUNT   |
|1994-01-01|10      |
|1994-01-11|10      |
|1994-01-21|10      |
|1994-01-31|01      |
```

actual output

```
|          |COUNT   |
|DATE      |        |
|1994-01-01|10      |
|1994-01-11|10      |
|1994-01-21|10      |
|1994-01-31|01      |
```

Comment: Pleas provide a minimal example of input and the matching expected output

Comment: Please make your example reproducible and minimal (no `...`), the matching expected output is missing

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1994-01-01', end='1994-01-21'), columns=['DATE'])

df = (df.assign(COUNT=lambda x: 1)
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='10D')).count()
        .reset_index())

print(df)
#         DATE  COUNT
# 0 1994-01-01     10
# 1 1994-01-11     10
# 2 1994-01-21      1
```